# CSS grid layout

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to create a css layout like the following image:

http://i47.tinypic.com/34y4ewk.png

I've managed to get it sort of working but I cannot get the text next to the image as illustrated here http://jsfiddle.net/jVwf4/

Any advice on how to get the text next to the image?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flip the order of the `<p>` and `<img>` tags and give the `<img>` tags the `float: left;` css attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/wG9uH/5/

Answer (score 0):

you could make your HMTL block like this:

```
<div>
    <p class="title">Cape Town<img width="100" height="75" src="http://www.geonames.org/img/wikipedia/131000/thumb-130255-100.jpg"></p>
</div>
```

and then float the image left like this:

```
.title img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```